# System.Data.Datarow C# error

Tags: c#, vb.net

So I'm in the verge of creating my first C# system. I use my vb.net system to use as my reference.

This is the code on my vb.net system:

```
Dim value As Integer = Val(dt.Rows(0).Item("TransID"))
```

I had to use an online converter and this is what I got:

```
int value = double.Parse(dt.Rows[0].Item[TransID]);
```

I got squiggly lines under "Item" - telling me that

> Error System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Item'
>   and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Data.DataRow' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

What could be the problem?

Comment: You are using `double.Parse` to assign to an `int`. Anything look a bit off to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line should read

```
int value = double.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TransID"].ToString());
```

`dt.Rows[0]` returns the first row, `dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]` returns the value of the "TransID" column as `object` from the first row. As `Parse` only takes strings, not objects, you need `ToString()` as well.

To avoid `ToString` you could also use the following, which is even better:

```
int value = (int)Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int value = double.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]);
```

Comment: Hey there thanos! Thanks for the answer! Although when I changed my code to your code I got a new error, 

"The best overloaded method match for 'double.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments"

:(

Comment: @Jhayzt Cool, then change it to double value = double.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TransID"])

Comment: You need to add `ToString` as in my answer. The result of `dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]` is `object`, but `double.Parse` requires a `string`.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou Your comment does not provide the solution.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou By the way: It's much better to *not* use `ToString` and `double.Parse`, but instead use `Convert.ToDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]
```

This should be working.

Comment: This won't compile ;-)

Comment: I've placed 'Use this' in the code block, off course, this should not be, so just remove the 'Use this'. I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
int value = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["TransID"]);
```

*or you can also use column index if you know it:*

**Assuming that required column is 3rd column in the datatable:**

```
  int value = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the Field Method on DataRow which would look like this:

```
int value = dr.Rows[0].Field<int>("TransID");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field